# CSS override using same name?

Tags: html, css

I'm playing around with HTML5 and CSS3.  As you can see below I want a site wide `<p>` tag style but then in the footer I would like a `<p>` tag in there as well but to have a different color and no rounding.

```
p {
    background-color: #1a315f;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow:5px -5px 10px #000000;
}

footer {
    width:100%;
}

footer p{
    background-color: #FEAF48;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;     
}
```

As you can see in this [link](http://godsurfer.com/index.php) I get the different color, but the rounding still occurs.  What do I need to change to the `footer p{` so I don't get the rounding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
footer p{
    background-color: #FEAF48;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;     
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add this `footer p {-moz-border-radius: 0; -webkit-border-radius: 0; }`